# How to use Python's RotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm trying to do a test run of the `logging` module's [`RotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler) as follows:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

# logging.basicConfig(filename="example.log", level=logging.DEBUG)

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
handler = RotatingFileHandler("my_log.log", maxBytes=2000, backupCount=10)
logger.addHandler(handler)

for _ in range(10000):
    logger.debug("Hello, world!")
```

However, with `logging.basicConfig` line commented out, the resulting `my_log.log` file contains no data:

[image]

If I comment in the line with `logging.basicConfig(filename="example.log", level=logging.DEBUG)`, I get the expected `my_log.log` files with numbered suffixes. However, there is also the `example.log` which is a (relatively) large file:

[image]

How can I set up the logging so that it only generates the `my_log.log` files, and not the large `example.log` file?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Python provides 5 logging levels out of the box (in increasing order of severity): `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARNING`, `ERROR` and `CRITICAL`. The default one [is `WARNING`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#what-happens-if-no-configuration-is-provided). The docs says, that

> Logging messages which are less severe than *lvl* will be ignored.

So if you use `.debug` with the default settings, you won't see anything in your logs.

The easiest fix would be to use `logger.warning` function rather than `logger.debug`:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
handler = RotatingFileHandler('my_log.log', maxBytes=2000, backupCount=10)
logger.addHandler(handler)

for _ in range(10000):
    logger.warning('Hello, world!')
```

And if you want to change logger level you can use [`.setLevel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) method:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = RotatingFileHandler('my_log.log', maxBytes=2000, backupCount=10)
logger.addHandler(handler)

for _ in range(10000):
    logger.debug('Hello, world!')
```

Comment: At first it wasn't clear to me how this answers the question, but key point is that log messages which are not above the level set for the logger (in the `debug()`, `info()`, `warning()`, `error()`, `exception()`, `critical()` hierarchy) do not get logged (in this case, written to the output file).

Answer (score 70):

Going off of Kurt Peek's answer you can also put the rotating file handler in the logging.basicConfig directly

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
logging.basicConfig(
        handlers=[RotatingFileHandler('./my_log.log', maxBytes=100000, backupCount=10)],
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s",
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: what's the difference b/w rotating file handler and file handler.

Comment: [FileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler) sends logging output to **a** disk file. [RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) supports sending logging to **a rotation** of disk log files.

Answer (score 31):

All previous answers are correct, here another way of doing the same thing except we use logging config file instead.

**logging_config.ini**

Here is the config file :

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=logfile

[formatters]
keys=logfileformatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=logfile

[formatter_logfileformatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)s %(message)s

[handler_logfile]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
args=('testing.log','a',10,100)
formatter=logfileformatter
```

**myScrypt.py**

here is simple logging script that uses the above config file

```
import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

fileConfig('logging_config.ini')
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.debug('the best scripting language is python in the world')
```

**RESULT**

here is the result, notice maxBytes is set to 10 but in real life, that's clearly too small.
 (args=('testing.log','a',10,100)

[image]

Comment: for anyone else 'a' means append. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filemodes

Comment: also the 10 is the size in bytes and the 100 is how many backups  args=('testing.log','a',10,100)

Comment: @grepit, will you be able to provide any link to docs with all such availabe keys or the things in square braces, and how to write such .ini files!

Answer (score 9):

I found that to obtain the desired behavior one has to use the same name in the `basicConfig` and `RotatingFileHandler` initializations:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logging.basicConfig(filename="my_log.log", level=logging.DEBUG)

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
handler = RotatingFileHandler("my_log.log", maxBytes=2000, backupCount=10)
logger.addHandler(handler)

for _ in range(10000):
    logger.debug("Hello, world!")
```

Here, I have chose the same name `my_log.log`. This results in only the 'size-limited' logs being created:

[image]

Comment: In my 'real' application, I would actually like to have two loggers: one which prints to the console, and one which is saved to a file. I've read that in such cases, one should not use `basicConfig`, which is meant for if there is a single logger. So I would still be interested why this code doesn't work without the `basicConfig` line.

Comment: Look at my answer, it has an explanation, why you code doesn't work without the `basicConfig` line.