# Add a RotatingFileHandler to Watchdog logging

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I'm trying to add a RotatingFileHandler to my Watchdog, allowing me to keep logfile growth in check. For illustrative purposes, I'll use the [Watchdog Quickstart Example](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html).

I found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088496/how-to-use-pythons-rotatingfilehandler) explaining how to implement Pythons' logging RotatingFileHandler, but I get stuck when I try to combine both scripts:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log',  # added filename for convencience
                        level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # edited Quickstart example with RotatingFileHandler here
    logger = logging.getLogger('test')
    handler = RotatingFileHandler("test.log", maxBytes=2000, backupCount=2)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

The code doesn't generate any errors but keeps logging as usual. I suspect the RotatingFileHandler is only passed to the regular logger and not to the LoggingEventHandler, but I have no idea how to pass it to the correct handler.

Any tips are greatly appreciated,

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check watchdog's source code about `LoggingEventHandler`: http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/_modules/watchdog/events.html#LoggingEventHandler

As you can see, `LoggingEventHandler` just use `logging` to log. What you need to do is implementing your custom `LoggingEventHandler`.

For example:

```
class CustomLoggingEventHandler(LoggingEventHandler):
    """Logs all the events captured."""

    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def on_moved(self, event):
        super().on_moved(event)

        what = 'directory' if event.is_directory else 'file'
        self.logger.info("Moved %s: from %s to %s", what, event.src_path,
                     event.dest_path)

    def on_created(self, event):
        super().on_created(event)

        what = 'directory' if event.is_directory else 'file'
        self.logger.info("Created %s: %s", what, event.src_path)

    def on_deleted(self, event):
        super().on_deleted(event)

        what = 'directory' if event.is_directory else 'file'
        self.logger.info("Deleted %s: %s", what, event.src_path)

    def on_modified(self, event):
        super().on_modified(event)

        what = 'directory' if event.is_directory else 'file'
        self.logger.info("Modified %s: %s", what, event.src_path)
```

And then use your custom `LoggingEventHandler`.

```
event_handler = CustomLoggingEventHandler(logger)
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I've also added a formatter to the handler to keep the timestamp: 1) handler = RotatingFileHandlers(**args) 2) formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s') 3) handler.setFormatter(formatter) 4) logger.addHandler(handler)

Comment: This seemed a bit overkill. Adding a handler requires adding only one extra line of code to the example presented in the question.

Comment: @AriM. Based on the fact that `LoggingEventHandler` uses `logging.info`(Which implicitly call root logger), this is not overkilling. You either modify the root logger or create your own handler. Let's admit that modifying the root logger is dirty and hard to maintain as it will affect all sub-loggers. Especially when you are working on a big project. The good practice should be "Never use root logger directly unless you really want to."

Comment: @Sraw, fair enough. I only provided a "quick and dirty" solution because the Quickstart example was used (thus assuming the user wanted something without much effort). My proposed solution is just to get the user up and running as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the RotatingFileHandler as an argument when you call `logging.basicConfig()` like so:

```
logging.basicConfig(
        handlers=[RotatingFileHandler('./my_log.log', maxBytes=100000, backupCount=10)],
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s",
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Applying that to the [Quickstart example](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html)

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                        handlers=[RotatingFileHandler('./my_log.log', maxBytes=100000, backupCount=10)])
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Many thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56369583) for the hint.