# In Python 3+, what happens if I log more messages than a RotatingFileHandler is configured to handle?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

In Python 3+, I'm having trouble understanding the RotatingFileHandler.  In [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40088591/2023861) the user is showing a `RotatingFileHandler` with a backupCount of 10 and maxBytes of 2000.  This creates 11 log files each holding up to 2000 bytes (22000 total bytes).  What happens if I log more than 22000 total bytes spread across many different log messages?  Do the log files get overwritten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that it starts saving log info into a file. When the size of the log file exceed `maxBytes`, the current log is archived and the new log information is appended onto a fresh log file. A maximum number of `backupCount` log archives may exist, and archives are deleted from the oldest only when exceeding in number `backupCount`.

All this happen automagically for you.

---

## EDIT

I'll try to draw what is happening:

You start with:

```
app.log
```

when `app.log` becomes too big:

```
app.log  <-- Created fresh
app.log.1  <-- renamed from old app.log
```

This keeps going until you have `.number` files as specified by `backupCount`:

```
app.log  <-- You always append data HERE
app.log.1  <-- renamed from old app.log
app.log.2  <-- renamed from old app.log.1
app.log.3  <-- renamed from old app.log.2
app.log.4  <-- renamed from old app.log.3
app.log.5  <-- renamed from old app.log.4
```

when `app.log` becomes too large again and there are already 5 backup files:

```
app.log  <-- You always append data HERE
app.log.1  <-- renamed from old app.log
app.log.2  <-- renamed from old app.log.1
app.log.3  <-- renamed from old app.log.2
app.log.4  <-- renamed from old app.log.3
app.log.5  <-- renamed from old app.log.4
-- old app.log.5 gets deleted --
```

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) for more details.

Comment: I checked your link.  It says `The file being written to is always app.log. When this file is filled, it is closed and renamed to app.log.1, and if files app.log.1, app.log.2, etc. exist, then they are renamed to app.log.2, app.log.3 etc. respectively.`.  In the example, backupCount is 5.  The docs don't say what happens with app.log.5 is closed.  Are you saying that when app.log.5 is closed, then app.log is renamed to app.log.1?

Comment: @user2023861 I edited the answer, I hope this is clear now. Basically `backupCount` limits the number of backup logs that are kept.

Comment: I think I see.  So app.log.5 is always older than app.log.4, and 4 older than 3, all the way down.  Thanks for the illustration.

Comment: Yes, it is basically a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) (or [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) using a different terminology) of log files.

Comment: My RotatingFileHandler is not appending new data to the initial file, but different modules are writing to different backup files. I don't know why. That was not happening before the initial log got full.