# Do you have to reinstantiate the logging logger to have it perform file cleanup?

Tags: python, logging

I'm working with the code in question: [How to use Python's RotatingFileHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088496/how-to-use-pythons-rotatingfilehandler)

Specifically this bit...

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = RotatingFileHandler('my_log.log', maxBytes=2000, backupCount=10)
logger.addHandler(handler)

for _ in range(10000):
    logger.debug('Hello, world!')
```

I put this at the beginning of my code, but my requirements dictate that I have to build this into a daemon, so the code at the core of the application will run forever.

Do I have to reinstantiate the logger for log cleanup to occur, or is the check made every time a log is written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler), file management is done automatically by the logger when it is writing to the file, so there wouldn't be a need to re-instantiate the logger to trigger this behavior:

> When `backupCount` is non-zero, the system will save old log files by
>   appending the extensions ‘.1’, ‘.2’ etc., to the filename. For
>   example, with a `backupCount` of 5 and a base file name of `app.log`, you
>   would get `app.log`, `app.log.1`, `app.log.2`, up to `app.log.5`. The file
>   being written to is always `app.log`. When this file is filled, it is
>   closed and renamed to `app.log.1`, and if files `app.log.1`, `app.log.2`,
>   etc. exist, then they are renamed to `app.log.2`, `app.log.3` etc.
>   respectively.

This is further corroborated by the [`emit` method source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L65). `emit` is called to actually log the message [when its severity level is equal or higher than the one configured in your logger](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel):

```py
def emit(self, record):
    """
    Emit a record.
    Output the record to the file, catering for rollover as described
    in doRollover().
    """
    try:
        if self.shouldRollover(record):
            self.doRollover()
        logging.FileHandler.emit(self, record)
    except Exception:
        self.handleError(record)
```

As you can see, it tries to roll over the files whenever necessary before logging the message.